# What is the largest amount of data that a single x86 instruction will read-from or write-to the L1 cache?

Tags: assembly, x86, sse, avx, avx2

I just read up on [AVX (Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions), and it brought this question to my mind.

Comment: using repeat you can get a pretty good sized transfer.

Comment: `REP`-prefixed `st`ring instructions can transfer arbitrarily large amounts of data. Casting those aside, AVX-less 64-bit processors have `CMPXCHG16B`, which _can_ cause a total of 32 bytes of traffic (16 bytes read, 16 bytes write). In AVX, a misaligned 32-byte store could cause two cachelines (CLs) to be read and written. With AVX2 gather, up to 8 CLs could be read. "Core" CPUs and later have `XSAVE`, which can save 512+ bytes of CPU state. But the ultimate winner for me is TSX's `XEND`, which could in principle commit or rollback KBs of data, without the "cheat" feeling of string ops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure your question is entirely clear, but I think you're asking how much data can be transferred to or from L1 cache upon execution of a single x86 instruction?

If so, it's kind of an ill posed question. The cache structure, and even caching as a concept are not part of the x86 specification. This means, that the answer depends entirely on the underlying hardware. If there's a specific processor you have in mind, you can probably find the answer in the data sheet. What you're looking for is the cache block size, since cache managers like to write and read whole blocks at a time. However, there are instructions in x86 extensions (such as AVX and SSE) that deal specifically with large memory transactions, and they can write or read the cache as much as is required/convenient.

Comment: Right, that makes sense, the architecture may change but x86 is simply the ISA specification. So, if I were to pose the question as relating to Haswell specifically, where can I find the answer?

Comment: I have to clarify this: ISA stands for Instruction Set Architecture and Is the architecture. The implementation, or micro-architecture is what changes. As far as Haswell, this might be what you're looking for: http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/core/4th-gen-core-family-desktop-vol-1-datasheet.html

Comment: @OregonTrail, actually there are ways in x86 to interact with micro-architectural elements - a `wbinvd` instruction would invalidate the entire cache hierarchy, resulting in multiple writes of modified lines stored there, so it's likely to write "the most" data. However, it seems you want the largest possible chunk that can pass between the cache and the execution units, which in Haswell should be 256B, and future CPUs may expand to 512 (see http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2013/avx-512-instructions)

Comment: @Leeor, you bring up a great point. Almost any memory instruction could invoke a chain reaction of cache-coherence events that may involve reading and writing many cache lines. Yes, my question is about data transfer from the execution pipeline to the cache and vise versa.

Answer (score 1):

You never read from, or write to, any cache level explicitly, but under any reasonable interpretation of what you mean, it seems to me that if you're reading from L1$, the value is being read into a register, and if you're writing to L1$, the value is being written from a register, so for all practical purposes, the basic answer is always “the size of the register you're using” as the source/destination for the architectural instruction in question.

In reality, it's a little bit more complex than that, because it depends on the width of the path between the MOB (memory order buffer) and L1$, which is a feature of the particular microarchitecture. Recently, Intel CPUs (e.g. Core, Nehalem) have had 128-bit paths from MOB to L1$, but I don't know if the most recent (e.g. Haswell) have upped that to 256-bit to match the AVX register size. That's one possibility. The other is that a single architectural store of a 256-bit AVX register might decode to two 128-bit µops (micro-operations) in the back end. The latter seems more likely for Sandy and Ivy Bridge owing to the “double-ganged” use of two 128-bit execution units to achieve 256-bit AVX operations. I don't know enough about the Haswell microarchitecture to speculate about what it might do.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info has links with answers to your microarchitectural questions.  (esp. David Kanter's writeups for Sandybridge and Haswell).  SnB/IvB have AVX, but still only 128b paths to L1D$.  256b load operations are a *single* uop for ports 2 or 3, but occupy it for two cycles.  There is no dedicated store-address port (until Haswell).  Stores (as usual decoded into one each store-data and store-address uops) can run the store-address uop on p2 or p3 even during the 2nd cycle of a 256b load.  So max throughput (2x 128b load, 1x 128b store) only happens with 256b ops.

Comment: SnB's max throughput doesn't happen in practice because cache bank conflicts are pretty much inevitable at that throughput.  Haswell is a big step forward: 256b path to L1, no cache-bank conflicts, and a separate store-address port (which can only handle single-register addressing modes, though).  Most code is still L2/L3 or DRAM bound, though.

Comment: Anyway, +1 for answering the how much data in a single uop question, which sounds more like what the OP had in mind than single x86 instruction.